# C++ Why base class/struct constructor can't have more than one argument to be implicitly callable from derived?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, c++20

Why this can't work:

```cpp
struct Base {
    Base(int a, int b) {}
};

struct Derived: Base {
    // using Base::Base; // unless I add this
};

int main() {
    Derived d(0, 0);
}
```

While this can:

```cpp
struct Base {
    Base(int a) {}
};

struct Derived: Base {
    // using Base::Base; // without this line
};

int main() {
    Derived d(0);
}
```

**Note: C++20 GCC 10.2** (second example doesn't work in C++17 either)

What's the *magic* behind the second example in C++20?

Comment: GCC accepts it: https://wandbox.org/permlink/swiVgY4nUIrgju1I, but clang doesn't: https://wandbox.org/permlink/AkCbQT8aJo17J9Lh. I suppose it's a bug on GCC side.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Thing is I want just a (int, int) constructor. In your example there are three. I'm using gcc 10.2.

Comment: @Cansisti I made a different mistake, sorry

Comment: @Yksisarvinen [It also works on MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/565TrK)

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah, interesting. I take back my claim of a bug.

Comment: `Derived d{0};` [works on all three](https://godbolt.org/z/fjYT7a).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "magic" is that you're accidentally using *aggregate initialization*. In C++20 (and not before), you can invoke aggregate initialization by using parenthesis instead of curly braces, so long as no actual constructor (like the copy/move constructor) would have been invoked. This was done to allow indirect construction of types (`emplace`, `optional`'s in-place constructor, `make_shared/unique`, etc) to work on aggregate types.

Your type `Derived` is an aggregate, as it has no user-provided constructors and one subobject (the base class). So your use of constructor syntax will invoke aggregate initialization, with the first aggregate member being the base class. Which can be constructed from an `int` (BTW, it's generally bad form to not make constructors from a single parameter `explicit` unless they're copy/move constructors).

Generally speaking, unless you are intending to create an aggregate (ie: the type is just an arbitrary bundle of values), derived classes *ought to have constructors*. I can't recall when I've written a derived class that *didn't* also have at least one constructor. And if it is your intent for the derived class to have the base class constructors, you should *explicitly* spell that out whenever you want to do that. Constructors are not inherited without explicit say-so.

Answer (score -4):

The trick is to use a derived constructor.

```
Derived::Derived(int a, int b) : Base(a, b) {
    ...
}
```

Non-static members can also be initialized this way.

Comment: The whole point of the question is that he does not want to do this

Comment: OP already knows that. The question asks why the second snippet can compile, and why only in C++20.